# Serious problem with \usepackage{newtxmath, newtxtext} after installation

Tags: packages

MikTeX stops running after installing newtxmath, newtxtext and gives the following error

```
 (logsechy.aux)Trying to make PK font NewTXMI at 720 DPI...
The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
Running miktex-makemf.exe...


Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.



The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:



  C:\Users\ABU QOTAADA ASSALAFY\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\ABU QOTAADA ASSALAFY\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log


LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `logsechy.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file NewTXMI): Font NewTXMI at 720 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\ABU QOTAADA ASSALAFY\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log
```

Comment: Did you refresh the font map files via MiKTeX console?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: It it one of the items in  the `Tasks` menu in MiKTeX console.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. I hope it works. Newtx has been giving me serious installation problems.

Comment: I hope  it will work!

Comment: B.t.w., in case it doesn't work, check whether the `updmap.cfg` file, which is in `/miktex/config/`, contains the line `Map newtx.map`.

Comment: I tried to load the updmap from the cmd and I tried other suggestions on tex.sx, they didn't also work. After I updated the package database, the issues with the cfg file was resolved. Thanks for the suggestion.